# jWebSocket on mobile browsers

Tags: apache, mobile, websocket

I've developed a web application which uses `jWebSocket`.

I've put it together on an `Apache Server` and accessing the site with a desktop browser works fine.

But it's not working on mobile browsers, that is, I can see the static website but no dynamic changes are made (using `WLAN`; on a laptop using the same `WLAN` everything works). The required ports can be reached but no connection is being established with the `jWebSocketServer`.

I've tested it on `iPhone` with `Safari 6` and on `Android phone 2.3` with `WebKit` browser and `Opera 12`.

At least Safari and Opera natively support `WebsSockets`, so I wonder if there's a general difference between mobile and desktop browsers regarding this functionality?

(On the Internet, I found nothing about mobile web apps with jwebsocket, there are clients for native apps but this doesn't suit my need.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that on smartphones you can't connect to ports other than 80? Found contradictory info on this. My webSocketServer operates on port 8787. Although ip scanner says this port can be reached, is it possible that no connection is allowed on this port? If so, can I change this? If I can't, I won't get around using port 80 and a apache proxy, will I?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, but for me at least I can see the webpage , for the jwebsocket it sometimes work fine on my Kindle (rooted and having android) sometimes not, my browser is chrome on the kindle.